# Operations with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```
Words = ['This','is','a','list','and','NM,']
```

**Note:** Words[5] >>> NM, (with a comma(**,**))

```
New_List = []
for word in Words:
    if word[:2] =="NM":
        Words.insert((Words.index("NM")),input("Input a " + ac_to_word("NM") + ": "))
        Words.remove("NM")
```

Whenever I try to run this I get:

```
 Words.insert((Words.index("NM")),input("Input a " + ac_to_word("NM") + ": "))
ValueError: 'NM' is not in list
```

Yet "NM" is the in index 5. What's going on here? I am asking for word[:2] not the whole word.

I tried figuring out the problem,but no one was around to look at my code, and give me feedback, so I though maybe some people out there might be able to help. If you see a mistake, please show me where. **Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: Isn't the error message totally clear? You're trying to get the index of a string `'NM'` from the `Words` list, but it is not in there. `'NM' != 'NM,'`.

Comment: Well, "NM" is not in the list, what do you expect?

Comment: Do not modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: Yes, but I am asking for word[:2] not word by itself.

Comment: @JohnJohn2 can you be more clear.

Comment: No you're not. You're using `word[:2]` only in the `if` statement.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart So how would you suggest me to get the index for "NM" only then?

Comment: Better write what you are trying to accomplish and someone will write it better than this what you currently have.

Comment: If a word or part of a word in the list(Words) is equal to the string "NM", then first I find its position,add an input from the user in its position, and finally delete it from the list.

Comment: Why so many down votes?

Comment: Guys its not always clear what the errors mean. This, at most deserves _one_ downvote.

Comment: Why so many down votes? Because you can not read.

Comment: @JohnJohn2 Thank you for your comment. I'll pretend I didn't read anything,since I can't read.Thank you. I now will work on improving my reading skills.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac When you're compiling with a Microsoft compiler, maybe. The error said `'NM' is not in list`. Please tell me how you can be any more clear than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You're trying to access a string `'NM'` in the list that has no such item.
2. You're modifying the list as you iterate over it. Don't do this! It will have unexpected consequences.

An easier way here would probably be to iterate over the list indices instead of the items:

```
Words = ['This','is','a','list','and','NM,']
for i in xrange(len(Words)):
    if Words[i].startswith('NM'):
        Words[i] = input("Input a " + ac_to_word("NM") + ": ")
```

Notice that I'm simply *replacing* the `NM...` items with the result of `input()`. This is more efficient than inserting and removing elements.

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from *here*:

```
Words.index("NM")
```

`'NM'` is not `in` your list of strings.

Doing insert and remove operations on a sequence while you iterate over it is a bad, bad idea.  It is a surefire way to skip an item, or to double-operate on an item.  Also, you should not be doing linear searches with `index` since a) it is slow and b) what happens if you have duplicates?

Just use `enumerate`:

```
for i,word in enumerate(words):
    if word[:2] == 'NM':
        words[i] = input('replace NM with something: ')
```